# Что здесь значит “ещё и заиграть норовит”?

Tags: значения

> В раннем детстве он мало чем отличаются от остальных детей. Разве что жадностью. Своих игрушек никому не даёт, бережёт, предпочитает же играть игрушками чужими, **ещё и заиграть норовит**.

Источник: [Портрет предателя на фоне эпохи (Компьютерра)](http://www.computerra.ru/104393/portret-predatelya-na-fone-epohi/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Здесь, кстати, возможны даже три значения:

1. *Заигра́ть* — не вернуть вещь, присвоить ее себе. Но не украсть (как близко, но все-таки неверно отмечает @Dmitry), ибо *украсть* значит тайно взять чужую вещь, а *заиграть* значит занять (взять с разрешения), а затем не отдать, в частности (но не обязательно) при помощи метода, что в народе называется «не мытьем так катаньем» («да-да, конечно, извини, дома оставил, в понедельник принесу»).

   *Заиграть* можно не только игрушку или что-то иное, чем или что́ *играют*, но и любую другую вещь (книгу, например). Таким образом *играть и заиграть* — это в данном случае небольшой каламбур.

   Это значение фиксирует, например, Елистратов [в своем «Словаре русского арго»](http://russian_argo.academic.ru/3959/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C), но по мне оно не несет коннотаций с уголовным миром.
2. *Заигра́ть* — потерять. В словарях не видел, но хорошо гуглится по запросу *заиграть куда-то* в разных словоформах:

   > Володька умудрился заиграть куда-то чудо-пустышку резиновую, из области привезенную. Приходилось ему в марлю кусок хлеба заворачивать и вместо соски давать... [[1]](http://morozovka.net/stihi-k-konkursu-den-pobedy)
   >
   > Умудрился на морозе сломать накладку ..., кусочек отложил — думал приклею обратно..., но заиграл куда-то и найти не могу... [[2]](http://forums.drom.ru/mazda-familia-323/t1151666286-p734-print.html)
3. *Заигра́ть* — играя, привести в не вполне годное состояние, истрепать. Сравните с *носить* → *заноси́ть*, *гонять* → *загоня́ть* (о человеке / животном).  Это вполне буквальное значение. И оно фиксируется в большинстве толковых словарей: Ушакова, Ожегова–Шведовой и др. В эпоху винила в ходу было выражение *заиграть пластинку*.

   > Мои [кошки], например, любят огурцы, если спереть их со стола и заиграть до полной вялости. [[3]](http://pushkino.tv/forum/forum54/topic267/)

Первое, как видно из контекста, много более вероятно. Другие два приведены для ознакомления.

Answer (score 1):

В данном примере, **ещё и заиграть норовит** - означает, что он **стремится украсть** чужие игрушки.

Comment: Украсть - это тайком взять без спроса, а "заиграть" - взять "на время" и не вернуть, т.е. злоупотребить доверием.

Comment: Точно так же -- только в применении к книгам -- использовалось слово _зачитать_... Взял, дескать, почитать и не отдал -- "зачитал".